How to inject RevisionableStorageInterface()?
I have a module I'm trying to update to Drupal 11.
Here's the code:
  public function processItem($data) {
    $entity_type = $this->entityTypeManager->getDefinition($data['entity_type']);
    $storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage($data['entity_type']);
    $is_revisionable = $entity_type->isRevisionable();
    if ($is_revisionable) {
      $entity = $storage->loadRevision($data['entity_id']);
    }

However, Methods ::loadRevision() and ::deleteRevision() in classes \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface, \Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage and \Drupal\Core\Entity\KeyValueStore\KeyValueEntityStorage are deprecated, so I need to switch from EntityStorageInterface to RevisionableStorageInterface.
That change record could use a simple example; how can I get the revisionable storage?  There doesn't seem to be a way to get it from entityTypeManager, and I couldn't find a service to inject to make it available.

You don't need to change custom code. The storage you have loaded from entityTypeManager has this interface if it is for a content entity type:
$storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage($entity_type);
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\RevisionableStorageInterface $storage */
$entity = $storage->loadRevision($revision_id);

You can use the full interface to have your IDE autocomplete all storage methods of a content entity:
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageInterface $storage */
$storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('paragraph');
$entity = $storage->loadRevision($revision_id);

In the rare case that you have mixed entity types (content and config) you can check the storage before applying the method to avoid an exception:
if ($storage instanceof RevisionableStorageInterface) {
  $entity = $storage->loadRevision($revision_id);


I don't get it. I am loading a paragraph entity with $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('paragraph')->loadRevision($revision_id) and get exactly same deprecated warning. What is the fix here?

Split the code line and type hint $storage with PHPDoc @var.
